# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str api vk

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def get_online():
    online = 'https://api.vk.com/method/friends.getOnline?user_ids=246359314&fields=bdate&access_token=' + access_token + '&v=5.85'
    fr = requests.get(online).json()
    num_online = len(fr['response'])
    for i in fr:
        for b in range(num_online):
            Z = ('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get' \
                '?user_ids=' + str(fr['response'][b]) + '&fields=bdate' \
                                                        '&access_token=' + access_token + '&v=5.85')
            z = requests.get(Z).json()
            Q = z['response']['first_name']
            print(z)
            #friends.append(z['response']['first_name'].json())
            b + 1
    return None
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно записать данные из словаря "response" "first_name" в массив и вывести его. Как исправить ошибку? Словарь берется с api vk. Функция должна брать друзей онлайн определенного id пользователя и выводить на экран.

Comment: Вставьте, пожалуйста, код, в виде текста, а не картинки.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: А вы отпечайте `z['response']` и может увидите свою ошибку

Comment: @andreymal увидел лишь массивы в которых и находится информация. 
[{'id': 494904348, 'first_name': 'Bane', 'last_name': 'Atropos', 'bdate': '16.6.1999'}] 
Оттуда нужно вытащить first_name что и вызывает проблему

Comment: `z['response'][0]` очевидно, дальше со словарём вы уже умеете работать

Answer (score 1):

Искал долго, но нашёл:

```
id_name.json()['response'][0]['first_name']
```

[Источник](http://python.su/forum/topic/35165/?page=1#post-191596)